# Eclipse projects deleted from workspace after checkout to another directory

Tags: eclipse, jenkins

I've a code repository in which is commited an eclipse workspace (everything in the workspace directory except pdom files).
This workspace references several projects that are commited in the same repository.

If I checkout this repository to another place and open it with eclipse, the workspace is empty (no project anymore)

I suspect that eclipse stores projects location with a full path while I expected a relative path.
Unfortunately, I was unable to find in which file of the workspace are stored the projects reference.

I'm using this system for continuous integration with Jenkis. Each branch is checked out in a different directory.

What should I do to make it work ?

Edit : Even if the workspace references projects by their full and not relative path, opening a workspace should at least contain some projects...

Comment: What kind of repository (Git, SVN, ...)? It's unclear to me what your question is. The project locations are stored in the `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/<project_name>/.location` files. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: For me, it does not depends on the repository but in my case, it is mercurial. Yes, this is the file i'm looking for. I can see that the path is not a relative path... I will try to change it by hand but it's a binary file, not sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it by scripting the building of a new eclipse workspace with the headless feature of eclipse.
No workspace is stored in the repository anymore.